# Exportar variables en nodeJs

Tags: json, nodejs, variables, variables-globales

mi duda es esta , tengo un extracto de codigo el cual exporta una variable y  la quiero usar en otro archivo en  mi proyecto de nodejs.

este codigo esta en mi archi login.js

```
   var Request = require("request");
          Request.post({
            "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" ,"Accept":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc3VhcmlvIjoibmNvcnRlcyIsIkVtYWlsIjpudWxsLCJpYXQiOjE1NDkzNzAwMjJ9.BLHUJIRwvHp7xjRIqXQkWTqaEmDuoFSSIPFKlM_XiG0"},
            "url": "http://localhost:8560/api/Sesion  ",
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "Id_Usuario": fields.txtUsuario,
                "Clave":fields.txtContrasena

            })
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }

            console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            var token = JSON.parse(body)[0].token;
            console.log(token);



        },

        exports=token
        );
```

y quiero traer el valor de token a mi archivo router de esta manera

```
   let login = require("../login/router");

   token = login.token;
```

pero me arroja que token esta indefinido y no se porque razón

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi caso exporto resultados de un modulo a otra parte de mi código de la siguiente manera, es similar a lo que quieres hacer:

```
var request =require("request");
var token_export=()=>{

Request.post({
        "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" ,"Accept":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer ..."},
        "url": "http://localhost:8560/api/Sesion  ",
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            "Id_Usuario": fields.txtUsuario,
            "Clave":fields.txtContrasena})
            },(error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        var token = JSON.parse(body)[0].token;
        console.log(token);
        return(token); //retorno el token

        };

       module.exports=token_export;
```

Ya en el otro archivo donde deseas llamarlo haces lo mismo así:

```
let login = require("../login/router");

   token = login.token_export;
   console.log(token);
```

Es posible que te aparezca el mensaje de undefined , por que no encuentra cual es valor que quieres devolver.

Saludos!